# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION help (jLabel and MATLAB deployed JAR file)

Tags: java, matlab, exception, jar, jlabel

Hi my program needs to perform two actions subsequently:
1) read text from a [jlabel](/questions/tagged/jlabel)
2) instantiate a class from a [jar](/questions/tagged/jar) file. The jar file was built and packaged from [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) R2008B.

It runs fine when ONE of the two actions are performed, but for some reason crashes as soon as BOTH are performed.

I'd appreciate any help or advice as to where I should begin to start solving this problem.

Error Message that I get:

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d8b1117, pid=5648, tid=3568
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b19 mixed mode windows-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jvm.dll+0x1117]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Emily\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SourceTraceGUI2012\hs_err_pid5648.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Opening log file:  C:\Users\Emily\AppData\Local\Temp\java.log.5648
Java Result: 1





#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d8b1117, pid=1240, tid=4532
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b19 mixed mode windows-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jvm.dll+0x1117]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

#Current thread (0x0840f800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread"   #[_thread_in_native,id=4532,stack(0x0b6d0000,0x0bed0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000150

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x0840f8f4, ECX=0x0840f7dc, EDX=0x00000004
ESP=0x0becf1cc, EBP=0x0becf1d0, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x6d8b1117, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0becf1cc)
0x0becf1cc:   0840f8f4 0becf1ec 6d9c8c33 00000000
0x0becf1dc:   00000006 082f1c28 0840f8f4 00000000
0x0becf1ec:   0becf208 78791463 0840f8f4 082f1c28
0x0becf1fc:   0840f800 18594120 18594120 0becf244
0x0becf20c:   0c0d9c91 0840f8f4 0becf24c 0becf254
0x0becf21c:   082a0e58 082a0e5c 0becf224 18594120
0x0becf22c:   0becf254 186006a0 00000000 18594120
0x0becf23c:   00000000 0becf254 0becf278 0c0d2e17 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d8b1117)
0x6d8b1107:   01 00 00 5e 5d c3 cc cc cc 55 8b ec 56 8b 75 08
0x6d8b1117:   c7 86 50 01 00 00 05 00 00 00 83 3d bc fa b1 6d 


Stack: [0x0b6d0000,0x0bed0000],  sp=0x0becf1cc,  free space=8188k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [jvm.dll+0x1117]
C  [jvm.dll+0x118c33]
C  0x78791463
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
 v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
```